# Emacs org-babel auto-loading?

Tags: emacs, clojure, org-mode, literate-programming

I'm currently learning Clojure, and I'm evaluating sample code from the book
in `begin_src`/`end_src` blocks. Works quite well, as org adds structure to
otherwise unrelated pieces of code.

The problem starts when these pieces become related, i.e. sample code
for chapter on agents uses a function defined for refs two chapters back.
So on attempt of evaluating the last block from a new nrepl session,
an `undefined function` error is thrown. Then I have to find the block
where the relevant function is actually defined and evaluate that.
And I'm lucky if it doesn't depend on anything else.

One solution could be to re-evaluate sequentially all the source blocks.
That would certainly work, but a very large number of blocks would be evaluated
needlessly, as they're not among the dependencies of the block
that I actually want to evaluate.

I'm thinking that perhaps some mechanism akin to auto loading
could be implemented, e.g.:

```
#+begin_src clojure :defines square
(defn square [x]
  (* x x))
#+end_src
```

So that when I'm evaluating this block:

```
#+begin_src clojure
(square 5)
#+end_src
```

and "Unable to resolve symbol: square" appears, org will try to find
if any of the source blocks in current buffer define this function.

I'm open to any other suggestions to solve this problem, as long as
the solution allows me to effectively store the code samples from
the whole book in a single org file.

Comment: I think `org-babel` refers to this as "sessions", but not all languages support them, you'd need to check if Clojure module does. (AFAIK, Java doesn't for example). http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html#sec-5-2 here it describes it.

Comment: The session works fine for Clojure. The point is that I've got ~100 source blocks
in a file. And I don't know yet how to evaluate them all at once (and eventually only the
ones that are the dependencies).

Comment: I'm not aware of a general-case solution, but I'd imagine that Clojure-specific code would be in a `ob-clojure.el`, it shouldn't be a lot of code, so, maybe you could start reading there and see if you can add more keywords to trigger your own code that would manage evaluation of dependencies. I'd also look into `:noweb` (literate programming) because it somehow knows how to assemble larger programs from separate blocks of code.

Comment: Are you trying to evaluate them while working?  If you use session and evaluate on export it should provide the correct results as you work through the document.

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin, I have currently about 100 clojure blocks in a document. Sometimes I want to use a function in block 101, that was defined somewhere above without having to find it manually.
I don't care about exporting, I'm just going through a book's examples.